# How to change variable in movieclips and modified back to timeline

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I need help please. I have a problem with my program which I am writing in ActionScript 3. On the main timeline I have defined global variable "k", whose value I need to change in the movieclips and the modified value in variable "k" back to a function on the main timeline. I am a beginner and I do not know how to write it.

Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this syntax in your MovieClip:

```
MovieClip(root).k = newvalue;
```